# Objects stays solid when render in camera view

Tags: rendering, camera

When I activate render mode without view from camera it renders fine, but when I enter camera view and then try to render objects stays solid.[image: Camera view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have accidentally set a **Render Border** in your camera view, however, the border is so small that it appears that nothing is being rendered. I have highlighted the very, very tiny selection border in your picture below, but to turn it off use **Ctrl + Alt + B**. If you're interested in actually using it later, you can draw a new border with **Ctrl + B**

[image]